# Accuracy in a CNN model never goes high for training and validation set

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN model on [KTH](http://www.nada.kth.se/cvap/actions/) dataset to detect 6 classes of human actions.

### Data Processing

- Dataset consists of 599 videos, each action has 99-100 videos performed by 25 different persons. I divided the data to **300** videos for train, **98** videos for validation and **200** videos for test set.
- I reduced the resolution to **50x50** pixels, so I don't run out of memory while processing.
- I exracted **200** frames from the middle of each video.
- it normalized the pixels from **0-255** to **0,1**.
- Finally I one hot encoded to class labels.

---

### Model architecture

[This is my model architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq9eV.jpg).
And this is the code of the NN layers.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(filters=64,
         kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
         strides=(1, 1, 1),
         padding='valid',
         activation='relu', 
         input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))

model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=2,
               strides=(2, 2, 2),
               padding='same'))

model.add(Conv3D(filters=128,
         kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
         strides=(1, 1, 1),
         padding='valid',
         activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=2,
               strides=(2, 2, 2),
               padding='same'))

model.add(Conv3D(filters=256,
         kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
         strides=(1, 1, 1),
         padding='valid', 
         activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv3D(filters=256,
         kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
         strides=(1, 1, 1),
         padding='valid',
         activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=2,
               strides=(2, 2, 2),
               padding='same'))

model.add(Conv3D(filters=512,
         kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
         strides=(1, 1, 1),
         padding='valid',
         activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

---

**Training**

My problem is both training and validation accuracy do not change, and they basically froze from the first epoch. These are the training step.
These are [the first 6 epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCYNm.png) and here the [last 6 epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDuzc.png).
The Loss looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7HZ9.png). 
Training loss is very high, and the loss for validation doesn't change.
and the training looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxOEb.png).

I am confused, is the model **underfitting** or **overfitting**?
How I am gonna fix this problem? will **dropout** help, since I can't do data augmentation on videos (I assumed that)?

I greatly appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: For classification problems, you could first validate your libraries and algorithms with MNIST dataset.

Comment: But this is a video dataset, and it worked good for MNIST but not for this type of dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 0-1 values of frames and are using relu. In dying relu problem model is frozen and doesn't learn at all because relu gets maximum values b/w 0 or the weight*input if bias is not added. You can do 2 things to ensure that model does work properly altough I am not sure whether you will get good accuracy or not but can try this to avoid this dying relu problem:-

Use leaky relu with alpha>=0.2.
Do not normalize the frames, instead just convert to grayscale to reduce extensive training.
Don't take 200 frames from middle, divide all videos in equal amount of frame chunks and take 2,3 consecutive frames from each chunk. also try adding more dense layers as they help in classification.

I worked on almost same problem and what I did was to use Conv2d after merging frames together i.e. if you have 10 frames of size 64,64,3 each instead of doing conv3d, I did conv2d on 640,64,3 dataset and resulted in 86% accuracy on 16 classes for videos.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!! I will work on modifying my model according to what you suggest, and I will post the solution to this problem if everything works fine to me. :)

Comment: great, try using simple conv2d too, intuitively it should work because since consecutive frames are almost same so merging them together and then doing conv2d will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you use the 200frames of video as training data to classify an action. Your training data is having too much bias.
Since its a sequential data to be classified, you have to go for memory based architecture or concatenation model.

Comment: you mean using a CNN-LSTM or LRCN model. How should I do the concatenation between CNN and RNN in this case?

Comment: Either you can go for hybrid CNN-RNN model or concatenate sequential images into single frame for using in CNN. For eg: combine 225 frames into single image having 15x15 rows and columns. I would suggest to choose 25frames if the timeline of action to be classified is under 5sec.